# Laravel 5.5 Package Commands Won't Register

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.5

I have a package for Laravel 5.5 and in the `CommandsServiceProvider` `boot()` method, I have:

```
if($this->app->runningInConsole()){
    $this->commands([
        MyCommandClass:class,
    ]);
}
```

Then, my `MyCommandClass` looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Testing\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MyCommandClass extends Command
{
    protected $signature = "execute:test";

    protected $description = "Description of the command";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    { 
        $this->info('Command Executed');
    }
}
```

The issue is that Artisan does not list the command when I run `php artisan` and when I try to run the command with `php artisan execute:test` it tells me the command is not defined.

What am I missing here? I followed the documentation for [registering package commands in Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#commands)

Comment: MyCommandClass must be the same as the class name.

Comment: Yes, it is in my case, just a typo here. I updated the question, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Troyer, have you created Package Commands in 5.5 yet? I can't find any other documentation other than what Laravel provides since it's so new. Just seems like I'm missing something here...

Comment: When I move the MyCommandClass to the App/Console/Commands folder and add it to Kernal manually it works fine, just trying to load through a package doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you added the `CommandServiceProvider` in your `config/app.php` file?

Comment: I thought it was loaded via Automatic Package Discovery...I have a composer file in the package with `"Testing\\Commands\\": "packages/testing/commands/src/"` in the `autoload psr-4` field

Comment: The auto discovery is actually `"Testing\\Commands\\CommandsServiceProvider"` in `extra laravel providers`, but I have that there too

Comment: Maybe related https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20863#event-1229756418

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the Auto discovery only works when pulling a package from a Git Repo via Composer. When developing a package, the composer files within the package do not seem to auto load.